# Parsing JSON with Alamofire Swift

Tags: json, ios, swift, alamofire

Добрый день есть такие json данные:

```
{
    meta =     {
        limit = 20;
        next = "<null>";
        offset = 0;
        previous = "<null>";
        "total_count" = 9;
    };
    objects =     (
                {
            description = "Длина: 906 метров<br> Ширина: 35 метров<p>  <b>Название</b><br> Рабочее название моста было Старо-Невский. Но, когда мост был практически готов, его переименовали в честь новгородского князя Александра Невского. Это случилось  15 мая 1965 года.<p>  <b>Факты</b><br> Соединяет южную и северную части города.<p>  Был самым длинным мостом в городе до того, как в 2004 году открыли Большой Обуховский мост.<p>  Мост семипролетный, центральный пролет длиной 50 метров — разводной. Пять пролетов расположены над зеркалом реки, а два крайних — над набережными.<p>  В конструкции моста использовали стальные тросы диаметром 70 мм. Они стягивают отдельные части моста. Натяжение тросов регулируется в зависимости от температуры воздуха. В холодную погоду натяжение ослабляется, при высокой температуре ванты дополнительно натягиваются.<p>";
            "description_eng" = "The bridge was built from 1960 to 1965 and it named after the legendary Russian military commander and politician Alexander Nevsky. The bridge connects Alexander Nevsky Square and Zanevsky prospect thus linking the southern and the northern parts of the city.The newly opened bridge named after the Alexander Nevsky Monastery (Lavra) serves as a part of convenient express motorway, where the traffic is arranged on 2 levels \U2013 on the embankments under the bridge and on the bridge itself. Impressing with its dimensions (spans of 110 and 123,5 meters, the beams of 5 000 tones each, the central 50 meters long drawing span), the bridge was also unique for its technical innovations: iron-concrete support shells, improved beam span support, hydraulically driven mechanism of drawing were firstly used in construction of Alexander Nevsky Bridge by the team of leading architects and engineers of Lengiprotransmost Design Institute.  Until 2004, when the Big Obukhovsky Bridge was built, the Alexander Nevsky bridge was the longest bridge across the Neva River in Saint Petersburg. Its length is 905.7 meters, and it is 35 meters wide. Designed by the group of architects - A. Zhuk, S. Mayofis and Y. Sinitsa - the bridge has complemented the look of adjacent buildings in surrounding area. The project was led by a team of engineers of the \"Lengiprotransmost\" institute. Proof-testing was done by means of a column of army tanks and on November 5, 1965 the bridge was open for traffic.";
            divorces =             (
                                {
                    end = "05:10:00";
                    id = 14;
                    start = "02:20:00";
                }
            );
            id = 2;
            lat = "59.925602";
            lng = "30.395119";
            name = "Мост Александра Невского";
            "name_eng" = "Alexander Nevsky Bridge";
            "photo_close" = "photos/Alexandra_Nevskogo_open.png";
            "photo_open" = "photos/Alexandra_Nevskogo_closed.png";
            public = 1;
            "resource_uri" = "/api/v1/bridges/2/";
        } ...// Дальше подобные данные из массива object
}
```

И есть такая структура:

```
struct BridgeResponse: Codable {
    //let meta:[Meta]
    let objects: [Bridge]
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let limit: Int
    let next: String?
    let offset: Int
    let previous: String?
    let total_count: Int
}

struct Bridge: Codable {
    let description: String
    let divorces: [Divorces]
    let id: Int
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
    let name: String
}

struct Divorces: Codable {
    let end: String
    let id: Int
    let start: String
}
```

В нее нужно записать эти данные с помощью Alamofire. Я пока что новичок в swift и не совсем понимаю, как именно записать данные в структуру, а не просто вывести их дальше

Comment: Что значит "просто вывести их дальше"? Вас конкретно просят написать конвертер, которые данные из json-формата будет переводить в модель, для дальнейшего использования. Это можно делать напрямую, средствами основного фреймворка, а можно использовать стороннюю библиотеку, например Alamofire. В чем вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
request(yourAlamofireRequest).validate().responseData { responseData in
  switch responseData.result {
  case .success(let data):
    do {
      let bridgeResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(BridgeResponse.self, from: jsonData)
      print("Objects: \(bridgeResponse.objects)")
    }
    catch {
      print("Error decoding jsonData: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  case .failure(let error):
    print("Request error: \(error)")
  }
}
```